# Browser keeps javascript cache even disabling etag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http-headers, browser-cache

I'm developing a panel which allows the user change its website's infos. In my current attempt I'm trying to change one menu name. For this change to happen I'm manipulating a JSON file on server-side on nodejs. This JSON file contains all settings of the website, as for example the menu names.

The logic works fine on server-side but I can't see the change on the page. I can see the new javascript content coming on devtool but the name of the menu does not change on the html. If I open the page again **in an incognito window it works great**, I can see the new changes.

**I just realised I have the same problem on incognito window. See my comment below.**

I'm providing the files by Express static method.

```
app.use('/templates', express.static(__dirname + '/live-pages/', {
    etag: false,
    maxage: 0,
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    setHeaders: function(res, path) {
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
        res.header('Expires', '-1');
        res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    }
}));
```

I've tried to disable etag like this as well (just for tests)

```
app.disable('etag');
```

I'm using a querystring on < script > tag to load the javascript like this:

> http://localhost:3319/templates/mypage/src/config/config.js?rel=0.47687368863262236

The config.js headers:

**Response header**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Auth-Token
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Nov 2016 08:20:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 07:53:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

**Request header**

```
GET /templates/mypage/src/config/config.js?rel=0.47687368863262236 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3319
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3319/templates/mypage/?a=1111111
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1904943772.1473524677
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 09 Nov 2016 20:59:36 GMT
```

None of the tries worked.

**As you can see the latest name is "wwwwwwww"**

[image]

**On my page I see "ABOUT US kkkkkkk" which is the old one.**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

That's really weird! I've just renamed my index.html file to 444.html and the cache still there!

I also added:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

No difference!

I'm wondering if could be something related to AngularJS 1.x. This is a SPA in AngularJS 1.x.

Comment: What headers were you serving the content with before you started trying to fix the problem?

Comment: I didn't change anything on the headers before. I think it was as default. My only change was the etag thing on server.

Comment: I just realised that even in incognito window I have the same problem. I can only see the fresh content when I access for the first time in a different browser

Comment: Then what were the default headers? (You should be able to override the local cache from javascript by doing a location.reload(true) but not all browsers behave properly - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp - use a frame to repopulate non html content).

Comment: You mean when I access my file like: http://localhost:3319/templates/mypage/src/config/config.js?rel=0.47687368863262236 ? I can post the request/response headers on devtool

Comment: Add a no-cache to your cache control header. As is your headers don't match your intent.

Comment: I updated the question with my latest try on Express static middleware and the new response header too but still the same problem. You can see now it's returning with 200 OK. The location.reload() didn't work.